# Python Elementtree SubElement incorrect

Tags: python, elementtree

I am trying to add a SubElement to a separate SubElement and I can't figure out why the output xml is coming out incorrectly.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

def CreateXml(list):
    Channel = ET.Element("Channel")
    cell    = ET.SubElement(Channel,"cell")   
    pngIcc0 = ET.SubElement(cell,"InputIcc0")
    pngIcc0.set("StructName","pngImage")
    pngIcc0.text = "DataBuffer_t"
    type0   = ET.SubElement(pngIcc0,"DataType")
    type0.set("Type","dataBuffer_t")
    pngOut0 = ET.SubElement(cell,"OutputIcc0")
    pngOut0.set("StructName","rawImage")
    pngOut0.text = "DataBuffer_t"
    tree = ET.ElementTree(Channel)
    tree.write("E:\Programming/ChannelCreation.xml")
```

The Resulting xml looks like

```xml
<InputIcc0 StructName="pngImage">
     DataBuffer_t
 <DataType Type="dataBuffer_t"/>
</InputIcc0>
```

If i want to make Type0 a child of pngIcc0 which is a child of cell what is the correct way to do it? Or am i going about this completly wrong. I don't have much experience with python of xml.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What output did you expect?

Comment: Your script produces `<Channel><cell><InputIcc0 StructName="pngImage">DataBuffer_t<DataType Type="dataBuffer_t" /></InputIcc0><OutputIcc0 StructName="rawImage">DataBuffer_t</OutputIcc0></cell></Channel>` when not displayed in a browser, which looks correct to me.

Comment: I expected the text DataBuffer_t to be on the same line after "pngImage"> In much the same way that <OutputIcc0 StructName="rawImage">DataBuffer_t</OutputIcc0> is all on the same line when viewed in a browser. Is it simple just a weird way its displayed when opened in a browser? It just looke weird to have the text DataBuffer_t be on its own line

Comment: That is your browser formatting the XML for you. Don't use a browser to verify whitespace details like that, use a text editor instead.